# Unity. Заменить конструкцию проверки существования компонента (GetComponent<>())

Tags: c#, unity3d

Интересует вопрос, как можно заменить конструкции проверки компонента на менее объёмные, и можно ли это вообще сделать?

Пример:

```
if (GetComponent<Rigidbody>())
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(...);
```

Или другой:

```
if (GetComponent<Rigidbody>())
    _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
```

Comment: Напиши свой метод

Comment: `if (GetComponent<Rigidbody>())` это ж не скомпилится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (...TryGetComponent(out ComponentType component)
{
    component...
}
```

и далее уже к component обращаться. Вообще, судя по твоему примеру, тебе этот компонент можно единожды в Awake закэшировать:

```
private Rigidbody _rigidbody;

private void Awake()
{
    _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidody>();
}
```

и потом уже по ссылке обращаться `_rigidbody.AddForce(...)`.

И, чтобы не делать проверку во втором случае, нужно добавлять атрибут [RequireComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RequireComponent.html) к твоему MonoBehaviour компоненту и тогда, если нужного компонента нет, то он при старте сцены добавится либо просто не даст повесить скрипт на объект, у которого нет нужных компонентов.

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class SomeComponent : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody _rigidbody;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidody>();
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.TryGetComponent(out IDamageable damageable))
        {
            damageable.ApplyDamage(10f);
        }
    }

    public void Move(Vector3 direction)
    {
        _rb.velocity = direction;
    }
}
```

Что-то типа этого.

Comment: супер, спасибо.
насчёт примера в коллизии, как раз в подобных и стал задумываться как сократить запись